# Rails activeadmin with enumerateit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, activeadmin, enumerate

I have a rails project with active admin that has a model with a field that is a string with enumerate_it:

```
class PrivacyType < EnumerateIt::Base
  associate_values(
    private: [1, 'Private'],
    public: [2, 'Public'] )
end
```

In the form everything work as expected and there's a dropdown list with the options `private`and `public`:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Details' do
    f.input :privacy_type, as: :select, collection: PrivacyType.to_a
  end
end
```

Bit in the index, it shows the numbers `1` and `2` instead of the text.
It is like this:

```
index do
  columns :privacy_type
end
```

What do I need to do to have the text `private` or `public` written instead of the numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
index do
  columns :privacy_type do |record|
    PrivacyType.value_for(record.privacy_type)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, just a small details, it's `column` and not `columns`, and if should be `.key_for(record.privacy_type.to_i`. Thanks a lot!